# Ignoring field in Code First with exception of using SP

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having a bit of an issue with Code First.  Recently I was requested to add 3 fields to a grid to display the Stock Quantity, Measure, and Primary Location of Products.  The problem is, none of the above are in the same tables.  To get around this, so I thought, I added 3 nullable columns to my EF table for the Product and then built a stored procedure to get my data.  The grid loads properly and all seemed good.  Then I tried to edit an item and got the following message:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'StockQuantity'.
Invalid column name 'Measure'.
Invalid column name 'PrimaryLocation'.

I'm trying to figure out how to force Entity to ignore those fields but am coming up empty handed.  My question is is there a way to ignore the fields with exception to when I'm pulling them from my SP?

Below is the code I have for them in my Code First:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Used when getting the List for Products
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int? StockQuantity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used when getting the List for Products
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Measure { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used when getting the List for Products
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string PrimaryLocation { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `NotMapped` attribute to the property.

Edit: This is a quick fix, I don't think in the end you should use your entities directly as view models.

Comment: I have tried to add the NotMapped attribute but cannot get it to work due that I can't get the dll for the reference.  I am starting to think that you're right though about not using an entity this way and may create a different entity for this case alone.  Thanks.

Comment: I see, I thought I had both but apparently didn't have Entity Framework.  Thanks.  Still thinking I'm going to create a different entity like you suggested.